# How can I reset XmlTextWriter.WriteValue after it fails to write

Tags: c#, xmltextwriter

In certain conditions that I cannot predict the following expression that uses a XmlTextWriter

`writer.WriteValue(value)`

throws an `ArgumentException` because the data does contain invalid XML characters.

When the Exception is thrown I can fix the XML by sanitizing the string like this

```
var validXmlChars = text.Where(XmlConvert.IsXmlChar).ToArray();
return new string(validXmlChars);
```

The problem is that when I try to do that and perform the write operation again, I get an InvalidOperationException that says that

*The Content token in Error state will cause the XML to be invalid*

Is there a way to reset the XmlTextWriter and write the value again with WriteValue so I can write the proper string after an exception has occurred?

Thank you.

Comment: why not writer.WriteValue(new string(value.Where(XmlConvert.IsXmlChar).ToArray())); // I mean do it before exception?

Comment: The string of text can be long and I didn't want to run this operation if it's not necessary